# If you're doing binary search on a 2D array, how does matrix[mid/n][mid%n] give you the middle value?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, binary-search

I'm trying to understand the following [solution from Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/discuss/26248/6-12-lines-O(log(m)-%2B-log(n))-myself%2Blibrary):

```
def searchMatrix(self, matrix, target):
    n = len(matrix[0])
    lo, hi = 0, len(matrix) * n
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo + hi) / 2
        x = matrix[mid/n][mid%n]
        if x < target:
            lo = mid + 1
        elif x > target:
            hi = mid
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

How does `matrix[mid/n][mid%n]` give you the middle value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mid` is the index of the linear version of the m*n matrix.  You need to convert that into row and column indices.  What you see is the long-known conversion for `q` given `n` columns: `row = int(q / n)`, `col = q % n`.

It may help to view this with n = 10; in this case, `mid` is the straightforward, base-ten number.  The first digit is the row, the second is the column.  Visualize:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 ...
```

Do you see how that works?  The tens digit (row = mid // 10) and the ones digit (col = mid % 10) form the indices into the 10-column matrix.

Comment: `The first digit is the row, the second is the column`: this is a great example. thank you! your matrix turned on the light for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of traversing the array in linear fashion and converting from a linear index into the 2-d indexes into the array.  If you have a 3x3 array, you have 9 cells. In row major (create the linear indexes by going across the rows), numbered 0-8, the linear index would look like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

The 2-d indexes would be:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
```

The trick is that mid/n is the row and mid%n is the column. Checking the whole array means checking all 9 elements. 4/3 is 1, the middle. 4%3 is also 1, again the middle. It depends on knowing that / is integer division and % is mod, or the remainder after integer division.

I think its a cool problem because it uses both the two kinds of division and the way 2d matrixes are created out of one dimensional memory.

Comment: Good illustration. Thanks.